# MySQL query firewall policy stats

Tags: mysql

Sorry, really new to mysql and drawing a bit of a blank on where it start with creating a query.

**What are you trying to achieve?**
To create a simple dashboard with 3 Gauges to display data from firewall policy stats. Basically I want a gauge to display the number of policies last_used less than 3 months, between 3 and 6months and over 12 months.

**How are you trying to achieve it?**
I have MySQL table containing columns

policyid int
last_used int - epoch
timestamp - timestamp.

I put the policy stats every 5mins so end up with this table

| policyid | last_used | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 511 | 1662808082 | 2022-09-10 12:08:08 |
| 511 | 1662808562 | 2022-09-10 12:16:44 |
| 511 | 1662809702 | 2022-09-10 12:35:04 |
| 511 | 1662809942 | 2022-09-10 12:40:02 |
| 511 | 1662810302 | 2022-09-10 12:45:02 |
| 511 | 1662810602 | 2022-09-10 12:50:02 |
| 511 | 1662810842 | 2022-09-10 12:55:02 |
| 512 | 1661442932 | 2022-08-25 16:55:32 |
| 512 | 1662808054 | 2022-09-10 12:08:08 |
| 512 | 1662808599 | 2022-09-10 12:16:44 |
| 512 | 1662809702 | 2022-09-10 12:35:04 |
| 512 | 1662809987 | 2022-09-10 12:40:02 |
| 512 | 1662810298 | 2022-09-10 12:45:02 |
| 512 | 1662810592 | 2022-09-10 12:50:02 |
| 512 | 1662810860 | 2022-09-10 12:55:02 |
| 512 | 1662811198 | 2022-09-10 13:00:02 |
| 512 | 1662811449 | 2022-09-10 13:05:02 |

I think the logical is to workout the MAX value for last_used per policy. Then just compare that to epoch times ( < 3months, between 6 and 9 months, 12 months) from current_time.

So as a start I tried

```sql
select policyid, last_used 
FROM STATS 
WHERE last_used >= 1654867964 UNION 
SELECT policyid,MAX(last_used) 
FROM STATS 
ORDER BY policyid;
```

But not getting the desired output. Has anyone got any ideas how this could be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not entirely clear what are you trying to achieve, but based on

> to display the number of policies last_used less than 3 months,
> between 3 and 6months and over 12 months.

You can use conditional aggregation to count the number of records based on last_used columns.

Try:

```
select  sum(case when FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)  <= now() and FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used) >=(now() -INTERVAL 3 MONTH) then 1 end )  as last_3_months,
        sum(case when FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)  <= (now() -INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used) >=(now() -INTERVAL 6 MONTH) then 1 end ) as between_3_6_months,
        sum(case when FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)  <= (now() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH) then 1 end )  as over_12_months
from firewall_policy_stats;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/Y-h60QD2

*Note*. I added some more data example just for testing purpose.
If you want to display `0` instead of null you could use `coalesce`

```
select  coalesce(sum(case when FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)  <= now() and FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used) >=(now() -INTERVAL 3 MONTH) then 1 end ),0)  as last_3_months,
        coalesce(sum(case when FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)  <= (now() -INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used) >=(now() -INTERVAL 6 MONTH) then 1 end ),0)  as between_3_6_months,
        coalesce(sum(case when FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)  <= (now() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH) then 1 end ),0)   as over_12_months
from firewall_policy_stats;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/R5JuoulF

**Edit**

> That’s pretty close to the output of that I need. However I only want
> to count the policy id once. So the highest epoch time from all the
> rows containing the same policy id

```
select  coalesce(sum(case when FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)  <= now() and FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used) >=(now() -INTERVAL 3 MONTH) then 1 end ),0)  as last_3_months,
        coalesce(sum(case when FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)  <= (now() -INTERVAL 3 MONTH) and FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used) >=(now() -INTERVAL 6 MONTH) then 1 end ),0)  as between_3_6_months,
        coalesce(sum(case when FROM_UNIXTIME(last_used)  <= (now() -INTERVAL 12 MONTH) then 1 end ),0)   as over_12_months
from ( select policyid,
              max(last_used) as last_used
       from firewall_policy_stats 
       group by policyid
    ) as tbl;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/rJLB3svf

Comment: That’s pretty close to the output of that I need. However      I only want to count the policy id once. So the highest epoch time from all the rows containing the same policy id.